# Redirect view to another if a certain condition is met

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'd like my Index controller to do 2 things based on the logged-in user's role:

1. If the user's role is "Master", then it should continue to load the Index view which contains a list of Companies registered on the website.
2. If the user's role is "Admin", then the View should redirect to the Edit view with the user's Company details preloaded into the view.

It's this second action that I'm having trouble with. Consider the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        if (String.Compare(Convert.ToString(Session["userrole"]), "Master", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return View(db.Companies.ToList());

        return View("Edit", new Id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["companyid"])) // this doesn't work
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

How can I redirect the user to the other view and preload the required data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["companyid"] });`  In case you have such Action Method of course. :)

Comment: Thanks very much vortex. Works like a charm... Please create an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        if (String.Compare(Convert.ToString(Session["userrole"]), "Master", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
            return View(db.Companies.ToList());

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["companyid"]});
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    ///Get your company by id here
}
```

Comment: Thanks again :) now I just have to figure out how to swap out my sessions... I want to start using encrypted cookies instead